# removing similar fields from a mysql select query using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the query:

```
SELECT ordernumber, orderdate, customername, orderline.isbn, title, orderline.numcopies, stock, shipmentbook.numcopies as shipcopies, authorname
                    FROM mousavs.author natural join mousavs.bookauthor natural join mousavs.book left join mousavs.bookorder 
                    natural join mousavs.orderline
                    ON book.isbn = orderline.isbn 
                    left join mousavs.shipmentbook
                    ON book.isbn = shipmentbook.isbn
                    WHERE stock > orderline.numcopies
                    ORDER BY  orderdate, ordernumber, ISBN
```

with which I get the table:
[image]

Here multiple fields are the same, save for the authorname where a book has multiple authors. Im trying to use "GROUP BY ordernumber" to display just one row for each book. 
However I get an error: `"Error Code: 1055. Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mousavs.orderline.isbn' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;

my database structure:[image]

expected result:

```
ordernumber orderdate   customername    isbn    title   numcopies   stock   shipcopies  authorname
N201699998  2016-12-24  "Mary Hall" 1491936169  "Kafka: The Definitive Guide: Real-Time Data and Stream Processing at Scale"    2   14  1   "Neha Narkhede"
N201799999  2017-01-03  "Aran Clauson"  1491936169  "Kafka: The Definitive Guide: Real-Time Data and Stream Processing at Scale"    1   14  1   "Gwen Shapira"
N201700004  2017-03-01  "Chris Reedy"   0321399420  "Databases, Types and the Relational Model" 1   5   1   "Hugh Darwen"
N201700003  2017-05-01  "Filip Jagodzinski" 0321399420  "Databases, Types and the Relational Model" 1   5   1   "Hugh Darwen"
N201700006  2017-05-15  "Chris Reedy"   1118063333  "Operating System Concepts" 1   16  NULL    "Peter Galvin"
N201700006  2017-05-15  "Chris Reedy"   1449328016  "Database Design and Relational Theory: Normal Forms and All That Jazz (Theory in Practice)"    1   3   NULL    "C. J. Date"
```

Simpler query:

```
SELECT book.isbn, title, ordernumber, orderdate, customername, numcopies, orderline.bookprice, authorname
                    FROM author natural join bookauthor natural join book left join orderline natural join bookorder
                    ON book.isbn = orderline.isbn
                    WHERE book.isbn = ?
```

Comment: looking to your sample yourn have not duplicated rows  so if you want remove the same values in columns you should work on presentation  ..side (client side) and not in mysql .. otherwise you can use  aggregation function for get only a value from multiple

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: For the group by function to work, you need to also add the isbn column as I assume it's a foreign key. This would however defeat the purpose of the group by. I believe the only way to solve this is with sub queries.

Comment: upadte you question and add the real expected  result (based on the sample provided)

Comment: @ChrisThornton Exactly it wants my  isbn, shipcopies, and authorname, no idea how the subquery should be formed though.

Comment: I'll see if I can figure out a query for you, is there any specifics for displaying an author?

Comment: @scaisEdge added expected result

Comment: @ChrisThornton no, it would be ok if only the first author were displayed.

Comment: @ChrisThornton ill put up a bit of a simpler query which has the same problem. I can sort out the more complex one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to the sample provided  you could use an aggregation function (eg: min on authorname)

```
SELECT 
    ordernumber
    , orderdate
    , customername
    , orderline.isbn
    , title
    , orderline.numcopies
    , stock
    , shipmentbook.numcopies as shipcopies
    , min(authorname)
FROM mousavs.author natural join mousavs.bookauthor natural join mousavs.book left join mousavs.bookorder 
natural join mousavs.orderlin ON book.isbn = orderline.isbn 
left join mousavs.shipmentbook  ON book.isbn = shipmentbook.isbn
WHERE stock > orderline.numcopies
GORUP BY ordernumber
    , orderdate
    , customername
    , orderline.isbn
    , title
    , orderline.numcopies
    , stock
    , shipmentbook.numcopies as shipcopies
ORDER BY  orderdate, ordernumber, ISBN
```

but you could also use group_concat( authorname  ) for a single result with all the autor in ine line

```
  SELECT 
    ordernumber
    , orderdate
    , customername
    , orderline.isbn
    , title
    , orderline.numcopies
    , stock
    , shipmentbook.numcopies as shipcopies
    , group_concat(authorname)
FROM mousavs.author natural join mousavs.bookauthor natural join mousavs.book left join mousavs.bookorder 
natural join mousavs.orderlin ON book.isbn = orderline.isbn 
left join mousavs.shipmentbook  ON book.isbn = shipmentbook.isbn
WHERE stock > orderline.numcopies
GORUP BY ordernumber
    , orderdate
    , customername
    , orderline.isbn
    , title
    , orderline.numcopies
    , stock
    , shipmentbook.numcopies as shipcopies
ORDER BY  orderdate, ordernumber, ISBN
```